# Relative Raphael Text

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael percentage-based text such as follows :

```
var paper= Raphael("holder", "100%", "100%");    
var e = paper.text("44%", "8%", "Initiated")
```

I want the text to stay relative to window size, when I refresh after resizing window.  However, although I'm using percentage-based text, the text is still not resizing accoring to the window. Does someone have an idea about this please?

Answer (score 0):

is "holder" resizing?  Raphael is using 100% of "holder", so maybe your CSS isn't telling "holder" to be 100% of the window.